# textual representation to the y axis

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I would like to give textual representation to the left y axis.
From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

In a way that:
0 - clear
2 - mild
4 - moderate
6 - severe

How can this be done?

Comment: create a 'enum' and accomplish the desired output

Comment: @TysonVignesh Could you explain more please? I don't understand how to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by overriding NSNumberFormatter

```
class CustomNSNumberFormatter : NSNumberFormatter {
    override func stringFromNumber(number: NSNumber) -> String? {
        switch number {
        case 0:
            return "Severe"
        case 2:
            return "Moderate"
        case 4:
            return "Mild"
        case 6:
            return "Clear Skin"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
    chart.leftAxis.valueFormatter = CustomNSNumberFormatter()
```